# How to keep a file's "open with" association from being changed

Tags: macos, file-association, blender

I have a folder of Blender files that must be opened with a specific version of Blender (2.76) (and I'd like to use a different version of Blender as the default for everywhere else, 2.79).

Whenever I make changes and save one of the Blender files in that folder, the "open with" preferences that I had previously set to v2.76 are changed back to the default Blender installation, v2.79. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by creating an Automator script that sets the default app for the files whenever something is added to their folder.

In this case, what's being added are Blender's auto-generated '.blend1' backup files generated during saving (Bonus: I also get to delete those unnecessary .blend1 files at the same time).

I'm not sure how you'd go about doing this if aren't files being added to your folder on a regular basis. YMMV.

[image: the pause is actually quite important]